# Clustering a mixed data set in R

Tags: r, mixed-type

I have a mixed data set (has factor and numeric variable types) and I want to do some clustering analysis. This is so that I will be able to study the entries in each cluster to tell what they have in common.

I know that for this type of data set, the distance to use is "Gower distance".

This what I have done so far:

```
cluster <- daisy(mydata, metric = c("euclidean", "manhattan", "gower"), 
               stand = FALSE, type = list())
try <- agnes(cluster)
plot(try, hang = -1)
```

The above gave me a dendrogram but I have 2000 entries in my data and I am unable to identify the individual entries at the end of the dendrogram. Also, I want to be able to extract the clusters from the dendrogram.

Comment: This what I have done so far:

cluster <- daisy(mydata, metric = c("euclidean", "manhattan", "gower"), stand = FALSE, type = list()) try <- agnes(cluster) plot(try, hang = -1)

The above gave me a dendrogram but I have 2000 entries in my data and I am unable to identify the individual entries at the end of the dendrogram. Also, I want to be able to extract the clusters from the dendrogram.

Comment: For Gower distance, take a look at the function `daisy` in the `cluster` package. 
For how to do clustering, a good place to start would be the documentation 
here at Stack Overflow. Try [hclust](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/8084/hierarchical-clustering-with-hclust#t=201706151323312767049)

Comment: `agnes` is a hierarchical method and you will need to decide where you want to cut the tree in order to get cluster membership.  This is very similar to the way that `hclust` works.  Again, it would be good to look at that documentation to see an extensive example.

Comment: I appreciate this but I don't seem to find anything that works for my case

Answer (score 3):

There should be only one `metric` in the 
`daisy` function. The `daisy` function provides a distance matrix of (mixed-type) observations.

To obtain the cluster labels from the `agnes`, one can use the `cutree` function. See the following example using the `mtcars` data set;

## Preparing of the data

The `mtcars` data frame has all variables on the numerical scale. However, when one looks at the description of the variables, it is apparent some of
the variables cannot be used as numeric variables when clustering the data.
For example, `vs`, the shape of the engine should be a (unordered) factor variable, while the number of gears should be an ordered factor.

```
# directly from the ?mtcars
mtcars2 <- within(mtcars, {
  vs <- factor(vs, labels = c("V", "S"))
  am <- factor(am, labels = c("automatic", "manual"))
  cyl  <- ordered(cyl)
  gear <- ordered(gear)
  carb <- ordered(carb)
})
```

## Compute the dissimilarity matrix

```
# Compute all the pairwise dissimilarities (distances) between observations 
# in the data set.
diss_mat <- daisy(mtcars2, metric = "gower")
```

## Clustering the dissimilarity matrix

```
# Computes agglomerative hierarchical clustering of the dataset.
k <- 3
agnes_clust <- agnes(x = diss_mat)
ag_clust <- cutree(agnes_clust, k)


# Clustering the dissimilarity matrix using 
# partitioning around medoids 
pam_clust <- pam(diss_mat, k)

# A comparision of the two clusterings
table(ag_clust, pam_clust=pam_clust$clustering)
#          pam_clust
# ag_clust  1  2  3
#        1  6  0  0
#        2  2 10  2
#        3  0  0 12
```

## Other packages

A  couple of other packages to cluster mixed-type data are
`CluMix` and `FD`.